# laravel 5 smtp mail not sending even after changing less secure app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I have already changed **gmail Less secure app ON** (at gmail setting) and my `.env` as following

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_ADDRESS=rejoanul.alam@gmail.com
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_PASSWORD=myPass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

After that my controller as following

```
    try {
      Mail::send('admin.users.email', $requestData, function ($message) use ($request) {
      $message->from(env('MAIL_ADDRESS'), 'Rejoan');
      $message->to(trim($request->input('email')))->subject('Account Updated');
     });
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();return;
    }
```

Every tie it is showing following error

> Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not >accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t11sm18420889pjo.21 - gsmtp "

My laravel version is 5.2, What I am doing wrong. Also tried by enable 2 step verification with app password option but not worked.

Is guzzle related issue? my compoer showing `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5"`

> When I try with `PHPMailer` library then work but laravel mail not working

Comment: when you changed the settings did you  run config:clear? and config:cache?

Comment: @ReubenGomes yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research it is found that laravel mail not worked with `tls` but `ssl` is fine. so after changing setting as follows it works
`.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_ADDRESS=rejoanul.alam@gmail.com
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_PASSWORD=myPass (this should be app password)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

normally your email password will not work. generate a app password from here https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
Note: without 2 step verification enable perhaps app password not work

Comment: this is not true if you turn on less secure app on gmail a normal password will work

Comment: @ReubenGomes when app password used then less secure on not required anymore

Answer (score 1):

The Error clearly says Username and Password not >accepted "BadCredentials"

Let me guess your MAIL_PASSWORD has a dollar($) or hash(#)

so in your `.env` use double quotes

```
MAIL_ADDRESS=rejoanul.alam@gmail.com
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_PASSWORD="my$Pass#"
```

like above...